# MySql Query to Select a table, iterate through the table to write a condition to produce a result table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, mariadb

```
User table :
employee_id
employee_name 
joined_date

Worksheet table :
id | user_id | start_date  | end_date    | attachment | Status
 1    56        2017-10-01   2017-10-07     somefile    Submitted
 2    57        2017-10-08   2017-10-14     somefile    Approved
 3    57        2017-10-14   2017-10-21     somefile    Approved
```

I have a user table and worksheet table. User submits work sheet on weekly basis. Now the admin wants to see Multiple-selected users worksheet on a random date selection.

In the worksheet table you can see, user 57 had submitted two worksheets in october month, and 56 had submitted only one worksheet

Form Values are :

```
$fromDate = 01 oct 2017
$toDate = 23 oct 2017
$employees = 56, 57, 58
```

The users joining date is saved in user-table.
If the user's joining-date is greater than the admin-selected-$fromDate, then the joining date becomes the fromDate.

Here the admin had selected a date range of three weeks. But the user 57 joined on second week. For the first week the user-57 is displayed with NOT-SUBMITTED. But actually the user did not joined on the first week. so that week to be skipped.

Note : The user may not submit his/her sheet for any of the week, only that record should be displayed as NOT SUBMITTED.

I managed to do this is Php and got the result in an array. But I am unable to do this using sql commands. I want to do this is query to achieve the pagination.

Logic I want to implment :

```
$fromDate; //from the Post request
$toDate; //from post request
$adminSelectedUsers; //from post request
$resultSet = []; // Declared for the result set
foreach($adminSelectedUsers as $userDetail) {
    // Deciding the from date
    $joinedDate = $userDetail->joined_date;
    if($joinedDate >= $fromDate) {
        $fromDate = $selectedDate;
    }
    $worksheet = select worksheet where userid=$userDetail->employee_id and start_date >= $fromdate and end_date <= $toDate;
    foreach($worksheet as $worktemp) {
        $resultSet[] = $worktemp;
    }
}
return $resultSet;
```

Now I want to implement the same logic in the Mysql. Is this thing is possible. Thanks in advance

Comment: so what do you want to achieve

Comment: It would be easier if you gave us examples of the two tables and what you want to see as a result

Comment: *"If the user's joining date is greater than the selected-from date, then the joining date becomes the from date"* ... why? Looking at the logic this is completely unnecessary. If they only joined on their `joined_date` there are going to be *no* worksheets submitted by that user before that date...

Comment: What exactly do you expect *worksheet* to be? You quasi-SQL query (`select worksheet ... etc`) specifies a table rather than columns, do you mean something like `worksheet.* from worksheet` ? Do you care about the user data at all? If not you can just run a (working version) of that SQL query you've got.

Comment: @inoxy, I have implemented this in Php and got the result as array. So I unable to do the pagination. So I am trying to convert this to sql query where I can give the pagination. this is a 2006 symfony orange_hrm framework.

Comment: @CD001 Your suggestion is valid. But we have added condition that, if any employee did not submit their worksheet that is shown as Not-submitted. If we are doing the same for new joined employee all the previous week will be shown as "Not-Submitted". Hope you got it.

Comment: Don't "iterate through a table"; so a `JOIN` so you do everything in a single step -- that's what SQL is good at.